# Do these temperatures indicate my computer is overheating?

Tags: temperature, overheating

Computer Specs:

- Processor : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700HQ CPU @ 2.40GHz 2.40GHz
- Installed memory : 8.00 GB (7.89 GB Usable)
- System type : 64-bit Operating system, x64-based processor
- Windows 8

Average temperature (idle) for Temp1 = 52Celsius

- Core0 = 38c
- Core1 = 32c
- Core2 = 35c
- Core3 = 36c

Average temperature (active, such as streaming live soccer/tennis match, or heavy gaming hours) = 62-72Celsius

- Core0 = 40c
- Core1 = 42c
- Core2 = 41c
- Core3 = 39c

Are these temperatures high?

Comment: Are you actually having any issues?

Answer (score 3):

### Your temperatures are acceptably cool.

For modern, higher-end machines, heat may rise to as high as 60, 70, or even 80 degrees celsius. Your machine is fine at these temperatures, even if you hear the fan(s) begin to spin at a higher speed to cool the machine faster.

Remember that at a temperature at which damage could occur to the hardware, your system will make a best-faith attempt to cool itself by slowing itself down or increasing fan speeds, and will shut down if it cannot cool itself to a safe temperature.

Intel ARK lists your CPU's maximum temperature (T<sub>JUNCTION</sub>) as 100 degrees celsius.

Comment: @DanteAdrian please mark the check mark to the left of my answer if it has helped you to your satisfaction.